# What does it mean by "I'm going too"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers Infinity War* (2018), on a weak signal, Pepper Potts calls Iron Man, who is on a spaceship:

> Pepper Potts: Come back here right now. Come back.
>
> Friday: Boss, we're losing her. **I'm going too**.

What does it mean "I'm going too"? Going to where exactly?

Comment: I guess FRIDAY says- “I’m going to....” and not “I’m going too”.. I still don’t get why there are downvotes

Comment: Too and to are different words. This question would be more appropriate for [ell.SE].

Comment: @OrangeDog Except I don't think we actually know which one FRIDAY said, all we have to go by is the scene.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I can double-check when I get home, but the subtitles say "too".

Comment: @OrangeDog Ah for some reason I forgot the DVD was released, yeah that'd be a good thing to look at.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

F.R.I.D.A.Y. says 'I'm going too', as in 'we're losing my signal as well', 'I'm about to cut out as well', or 'you're losing me as well'.

Comment: Hmm I hadn't thought of that, been a while since I've watched it but the transcript does add a comma after going which would back this up.

Comment: Yeah, the implication to me was that F.R.I.D.A.Y. is such a complex AI that she can't be run directly by the Iron Man suit and instead runs off servers in Stark Tower. Once he gets out of communication range of Earth Tony loses access to her.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the important part of the quote out it is:

> **F.R.I.D.A.Y:** Boss, we're losing her. I'm going **to...**

F.R.I.D.A.Y is cut off before it can finish the sentence. Presumably, however, it was going to boost the signal or find a way to strengthen it considering that it was losing the connection to Pepper.

Comment: LethalCarrot  So I think you mean that the phrase should have been spelled  "Boss, we're losing her. I'm going to_____" meaning that F.R.I.D.A.Y. is cut off before finishing.  If the transcript says "Boss, we're losing her. I'm going, too..." that would imply that the transcripter believed F.R.I.D.A.Y. was saying that its connection to Tony was also fading.  It seems to me that many people should probably be able to tell the difference in meaning from how it was said by the voice actor.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Can confirm that the subtitles (viewed on Netflix) do read as you have them.

Comment: With to not too?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yes, with a "to". So your answer seems to be more "correct" even though I originally thought it was a "too" and the other answer was more correct.... Might just be bad transcription though...

Answer (score 2):

The film's [official Junior Novelisation](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War_-_Destiny_Arrives) confirms that F.R.I.D.A.Y. was advising Tony that she was *also going to get cut off* ("too") as a result of Tony's distance from Earth.

> "Boss, we're losing her. I'm going, too." FRIDAY'S voice, and then the call, cut out. Pepper was gone, and he knew that she would be haunted by his absence until he talked to her again...saw her again. That meant he had to do what he'd come to do, and fast.
>
> <sub><sup>[Infinity War: Destiny Arrives](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War_-_Destiny_Arrives)</sup></sub>